# Shell Script: Go to specific line of the file and read the rest in unix

Tags: shell

I planing to prepare a master parameter file from my script like the below pattern.

```
>cat ReferenceFile.cfg

ENV_VARIABLE:
{
aaa='asdfa'
Temp_Dir='/asdf/casdf/asd/'
Script_Dir='/asdf/asd/adsf/'
}

ArchiveDetails:
{
FOLDERS      PATERN    DAYS_TO_RETAIN    MINIMUM_SIZE_THESHOLD(MB)
/aaa/bbb/      *             3                          300
/ddd/eee/      *.txt         4
/aaa/ccc/       ABC*         4                          2000
}

Exceptions:
{
EXTENSIONS
.sh
.ksh
.cfg
}

...
...
...
```

Inorder to read the content under ENV_VARIABLE:, I would need to reach till there and do the following.

```
cat /param/paramter.cfg | while read line
do
<Reach the line under EVN_VARIABLE>
eval $line
done
```

Inorder to read the content under ArchiveDetails:, I would need to reach till there and do the following.

```
    cat /param/paramter.cfg <Reach the line under ArchiveDetails>
    | while read FOLDERS PATERN DAYS MINIMUM_SIZE
    do
    ...
    ...
    done
```

Like wise, I would do it for Exceptions.
My questions is, how can I reach the designated section directly. Like The segment under ArchiveDetails or Exceptions etc. 
And Iam planing to exit the read as soon as I see '}' and use the 'break' command. Any other better approach?

Suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How flexible is your configuration file? It looks like you don't want to actually only read the next line, but you want to parse the contents of named blocks.

Comment: Also, what happens if your `ArchiveDetails.Pattern` contains, say, a `{`?

Comment: Iam trying to set the Enviornmental variable, and I wanted to store the details under the ENV_VARIABLE. I have more than one parameter value per line time to be stored, hence maintaining the section ArchiveDetails. And the list of all extensions that need to be considired as Exceptions, are maintained under Exception segment. But Iam open for Suggestions. Is there a better way to maintain these information? This configuration file is going to be accessed by many people, hence dont want to make it too technical. I felt, this structure, would make it more readable.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason the file must be formatted this way? It's important to understand whence the format because it will inform possible tools that can understand it better than handcrafted shell scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do exactly what you're asking is to use `sed` to delete everything up to the starting  line you're looking for:

```
sed -e 1,/^ENV_VARIABLE:/d < ReferenceFile.cfg | while read line; do
    ...
done
```

It's not difficult to extend that sed command to just return the "section" you're looking for:

```
SECTION=ENV_VARIABLE
CFG=ReferenceFile.cfg
CFGSECT=$(sed -n -e 1,/^$SECTION:/d -e /^{/d -e /^}/q -ep < $CFG)
eval "$CFGSECT"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Small note: a Hyphen is missing before the n.  Right syntax : CFGSECT=$(sed -n -e 1,/^$SECTION:/d -e /^{/d -e /^}/q -ep < $CFG)